# How to send ISODate in meteor.call method

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am creating an array of objects in client side in the meteor, and each object have modified date inside it as mentioned below:

**Client Side:**

```
student;
```

here `student` is an array of an object contains `name, id, roll_no`

```
var array = [];
student.forEach(function(singleStud, index){
   var single_obj ={
   "name":singleStud.name,
   "student_id":singleStud.id,
   "roll_no":singleStud.roll_no,
   "college_name":"ABC college",
   "college_id":"xyz Id",
   "created_date": new Date()
  }
array.push(single_obj);

},this)

Meteor.call('saveDetails', array, function (error, result) {
   console.log("data Saved Successfully");
});
```

**Server Side:**

I have used plugin [mikowals:batch-insert](https://github.com/mikowals/batch-insert) to insert an array which is equivalent to `insertMany` in mongo.

```
Meteor.methods({
"saveDetails": function (array) {
        try {
           studentDetails.batchInsert(array);
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }
});
```

when I save it the `created_date` is saving it as a string (`"2018-04-23T10:26:26.766Z"`),  but I want it to be saved it as a date data type (`ISODate("2018-04-23T10:26:26.766Z")`).

How can I achieve from the client side in `meteor.call` ???

Comment: Could you `console.log` the array inside the method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is actually a bug in `mikowals:batch-insert`.  `mikowals-batch-insert` recursively attempts to convert objects into a JSON format friendly with MongoDB.  As part of this process, it uses [underscore clone](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) to make [shallow copies](https://github.com/mikowals/batch-insert/blob/master/batch-insert-server.js#L61) of primitive types.  While `Date` is a primitive, it cannot be cloned with `_.clone`, so it mutates your date to a string (eww).  You should open an issue with `mikowals:batch-insert`.
2. Regardless, you **shouldn't be defining this data on the client.** The client could maliciously inject false information (which could break your application's logic). Instead, you should map over the input and inject the date into incoming objects.